# copying int to a string

Tags: c, string

I'am trying to learn c and therefore solving this [exercise](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A). My problem is in the part where I have to abbreviate a word. I am using sprintf to convert the integer to a string and write it into my old string. But however I try to achieve it, the last character of the string always gets lost. Why does this happen? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void abreviation(char *arr,int length){
    if ( length+1 > 10){
        char c = arr[length];
        sprintf(arr+1, "%d%c", length-1,c);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n,i,j;
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    char **arr = malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0; i < n ; i++){
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        char c;
        for ( j=0; (c = getchar()) != '\n' ; j++)
            arr[i][j]=c;
        arr[i][j+1]='\0';
        abreviation(arr[i],j);
    }
    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);

}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `getchar()` wants an `int` not a `char`

Comment: The way you pass parameters, `arr[length]` is always `'\0'`.

Comment: `arr[i][j+1]='\0';` --> `arr[i][j]='\0';`, `char c = arr[length];` --> `char c = arr[length-1];`

Comment: `sprintf(arr+1, "%d%c", length-1,c);` --> `sprintf(arr+1, "%d%c", length-2,c);`

Comment: `if ( length+1 > 10){` --> `if ( length > 10){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop you wrote to input the words stop at `'\0'`, at that point `j` is indexed to `'\0'`, and then in the `abreviation` function `char c = arr[length` `c` will always be `\0` and not the last char in the word (`arr`).

A simple fix is to change

```
abreviation(arr[i],j);
```

to

```
abreviation(arr[i],j-1);
```